# html pause canvas game works... but my resume does not. Why not?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently working on a canvas game. My pause functionality works but my resume does not. Ive seen other example on here with the similar problem but it's not helping. What am I doing wrong?

```
var paused = false;

document.onkeydown = function onKeyPause(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 80)
    paused = !paused;
return;}

var gamearea = {
canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
start: function () {
    this.canvas.width = 250;
    this.canvas.height = 287;

    ...more canvas css.........


update: function () {
    gamearea.context.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 400);
    document.getElementById("score").innerText = "Score: " + score;
    if (score == 20) {
        gamearea.stop(true);
        return;
    }
    if (targetGone()) {
        gamearea.stop(false);
        return;
    }

    if (paused) {
        gamearea.pausedGame(true);
        return;
    }

pausedGame: function (paused) {

    gamearea.canvas.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler, event);
    gamearea.context.fillRect(0, 100, 300, 100);
    gamearea.context.font = "20px helvetica";
    ... more canvas css ..

    if (paused) return; // <--- stop looping
    update();
    draw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
},
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem that you are having but I recommend this library for keyboard bindings https://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: unfortunately, for this project I can't use JS libraries. It has to be vanilla js... yay me! But thank you, anyways!

Comment: I'm not sure why `pausedGame` would call `update`...

Comment: Now that your loop is stopped, you need to resume it when paused is falsy, so `paused = !paused; if(paused === false) { gamearea.update(); //resume}`

Comment: I was able to fix my issue by resuming the loop by declaring    paused = !paused;
    if (paused === false) {
        gamearea.update();
        gamearea.start();
        return;

Answer (score 1):

requestAnimationFrame returns an Id that you can use to "pause" your game loop

Use cancelAnimationFrame(RETURNED_ID)

simple example

```
// global variable
let loopId = null;

function start() {

  ...
  loopId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function loop() {
  ...
  loopId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function pauseHandler() {
  if (looId) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(loopId)
  }
}
```

Comment: Not calling requestAnimationFrame like OP is doing will also stop the loop. Their problem is with resuming it.